# How can I pass an NSArray between two view controllers?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, uiviewcontroller

How can I pass an NSArray between two view controllers? The second view is called by a button in the first. The code for calling it is:

```
SettingsViewController *settingsView = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:settingsView animated:YES];
```

I've currently declared the following property in view controller A.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(Button) DISarray *buttons;
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the 2 controllers?

Comment: The second view is called up using a button in the first.  The code for calling it is:

Comment: As you noticed, pressing enter submits the comment :) It would be best to insert relevant code into your question.

Comment: Whoops added the comment too early.  SettingsViewController *settingsView = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];     [self presentModalViewController:settongsView animated:YES];

Answer (score 1):

Declare a [property](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html) in view controller A, set it from view controller B.

Comment: yep, that was what I was aiming for in my inquiry ;)

Comment: Is there a special way I need to declare the property?  I currently have:  @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttons. ;

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear what you're really asking here. The syntax for function calls in Objective C?

Note that you're passing an NSArray* -- a pointer to the array. So you aren't copying all the elements of the array.

```
@implementation ThisController
 ....
-(void) doit: (NSArray*) theArray to: (UIViewController*) thatController
{
     [thatController doSomething: theArray];
}
```